# Kibana 6.4 Runnin as Daemon

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5, kibana-6

I am using elasticsearch.zip , and kibana.zip in linux . Elastic search have option to run as daemon using (elasticsearch -d -p pid). it is working fine after we closed the putty. How can achieve the same for kibana . I tried with "kibana &". after closing the putty session , i couldn't access it . Any solution highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either start kibana process as start-up daemon once your elasticsearch instance is also set to start at boot time. Or else while starting it up manually use the `nohup` command to start it like: `nohup ./bin/kibana &` This way the kibana process will ignore SIGHUP such as closing the putty session and keep itself running.

Comment: How long it will run after closing the putty session. i executed nohub command and tried ps -ef | grep -i kibana .. i couldn't find the process id. any thoughts

Comment: It will keep on running as long as it doesn't get exitted or terminated. You are looking for a wrong pattern. Kibana is a node application and you should be checking the process using: `ps -ef | grep node`